# How to compare DTSs in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, compare, dts

Once your databases are converted from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005, is there any way to compare DTSs on two servers to see if they are still essentially the same?  I need to see if my dev and prod are the same, and comparing them manually is really time consuming.

If they were still in 2000, I could use the Red-Gate tool DTS Compare, but that doesn't work in 2005.  I can save each as a Visual Basic file, and then compare those (and that kind of works), but the steps may be output in a different order.  Is there something out there that is better?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, don't use DTS jobs in SQL Server 2005.
There are a complete new and reworked method to do those things: SSIS.

Here you find an introduction:
http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm

Yes, maybe you can't compare it perfectly, but DTS Jobs are run out of support since SQL 2005 (remember, we are in 2009 :) )

Comment: Yes, I know that SSIS is the way to go, but when I've got a lot of legacy code, that takes awhile to convert.  And in the meantime, I've got to maintain the DTSs that exist.